# Unable to copy parent model attributes to children?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a polymorphic association:

```
class User
  has_many :products
  has_many :subscriptions, :foreign_key => :subscriber_id
end

class Product
  belongs_to :store
  has_many :subscriptions, :as => :subscribable
end

class Subscription
  belongs_to :subscriber, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :subscribable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

The `Subscription` model holds the `Product` columns because I want to duplicate them:

```
create_table :products do |t|
  t.string  :name
  t.decimal :price
  t.integer :user_id
  t.integer :store_id
end

create_table :subscriptions do |t|
  t.string  :name
  t.decimal :price
  t.integer :store_id
  t.integer :subscriber_id # user_id
  t.integer :subscribable_id
  t.string  :subscribable_type
end
```

When I try to subscribe to a product by my link:

```
<td><%= link_to "Subscribe", { :controller => "products", :action => "subscribe_product", :id => product.id }, :method => :post %></td>
```

I get the error:

```
NameError in ProductsController#subscribe_product

undefined local variable or method `store_id' for #<ProductsController:0x705bad8>
```

Because of my controller trying to duplicate my product fields now:

```
def subscribe_product
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    subscription = Subscription.new(@product.attributes.merge({
      :store_id => store_id,
      :price => price,
      :name => name
    }))
    subscription.subscriber_id = current_user.id
    @product.subscriptions << subscription
    if @product.save
      redirect_to :back, :notice => "Successfully subscribed to #{@product.name}"
    else
      render :back, :notice => "Could Not Subscribe to Product correctly."
    end
  end
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? I don't understand why `store_id` and the rest of the fields that are to be duplicated are giving the `NameError`?

Comment: Change `product.attributes.merge` to `@product.attributes.merge` ?

Comment: @Zabba What do you mean?

Comment: Missing the "@" - you have set an instance variable named "@product" and trying to reference a local variable named "product". Line 2 of the subscribe_product method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the instance variable @product get store_id, price, and name's value, as follow:

```
def subscribe_product
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])

  subscription = Subscription.new(
     :store_id => @product.store_id,
     :price => @product.price,
     :name => @product.name
     )

  subscription.subscriber = current_user
  @product.subscriptions << subscription
  if @product.save
    redirect_to :back, :notice => "Successfully subscribed to #{@product.name}"
  else
     render :back, :notice => "Could Not Subscribe to Product correctly."
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is because of this line in your controller:

```
subscription = Subscription.new(@product.attributes.merge({
  :store_id => store_id,
  :price => price,
  :name => name
}))
```

`store_id`, `price`, and `name` aren't local variables in your controller method, and aren't in scope in any other way, so the computer doesn't know what they're supposed to be. (I'm not sure what they're supposed to be either; where are these values supposed to come from?)

I also don't understand why you are duplicating the columns between `Product` and `Subscription`. This seems to be unnecessary duplication of data. What are you trying to achieve by doing it?